# How can I get VID/PID from USB Flash drives in C#?

Tags: c#, usb, pid, usb-flash-drive

I need to perform a check on all drives and see if any of the VIDs/PID match a specific one, if it does I need to get the drive letter of that flash drive.
Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

WMI should be able to handle this...

You will have to add a Reference to the System.Management dll and you will need to have the:
"using System.Management;" line... See Link At Bottom for Screenshots, more thorough explanation...

```
using System.Management;
// Get all the disk drives

ManagementObjectSearcher mosDisks = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");

// Loop through each object (disk) retrieved by WMI

foreach (ManagementObject moDisk in mosDisks.Get())

{

    // Add the HDD to the list (use the Model field as the item's caption)

    cmbHdd.Items.Add(moDisk["Model"].ToString());

}


private void cmbHdd_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

// Get all the disk drives from WMI that match the Model name selected in the ComboBox

ManagementObjectSearcher mosDisks = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE Model = '" + cmbHdd.SelectedItem + "'");

// Loop through the drives retrieved, although it should normally be only one loop going on here

foreach (ManagementObject moDisk in mosDisks.Get())

{

    // Set all the fields to the appropriate values

    lblType.Text = "Type: " + moDisk["MediaType"].ToString();

    lblModel.Text = "Model: " + moDisk["Model"].ToString();

    lblSerial.Text = "Serial: " + moDisk["SerialNumber"].ToString();

    lblInterface.Text = "Interface: " + moDisk["InterfaceType"].ToString();

    // The capacity in gigabytes is easily calculated 

    lblCapacity.Text = "Capacity: " + moDisk["Size"].ToString() + " bytes (" + Math.Round(((((double)Convert.ToDouble(moDisk["Size"]) / 1024) / 1024) / 1024), 2) + " GB)";

    lblPartitions.Text = "Partitions: " + moDisk["Partitions"].ToString();

    lblSignature.Text = "Signature: " + moDisk["Signature"].ToString();

    lblFirmware.Text = "Firmware: " + moDisk["FirmwareRevision"].ToString();

    lblCylinders.Text = "Cylinders: " + moDisk["TotalCylinders"].ToString();

    lblSectors.Text = "Sectors: " + moDisk["TotalSectors"].ToString();

    lblHeads.Text = "Heads: " + moDisk["TotalHeads"].ToString();

    lblTracks.Text = "Tracks: " + moDisk["TotalTracks"].ToString();

    lblBytesPerSect.Text = "Bytes per Sector: " + moDisk["BytesPerSector"].ToString();

    lblSectorsPerTrack.Text = "Sectors per Track: " + moDisk["SectorsPerTrack"].ToString();

    lblTracksPerCyl.Text = "Tracks per Cylinder: " + moDisk["TracksPerCylinder"].ToString();

    }

}
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the win32 Class for CIM_DiskDrive has the following parameters:

*It looks as if "DeviceID" is what you want...

```
class Win32_DiskDrive : CIM_DiskDrive
{
  uint16   Availability;
  uint32   BytesPerSector;
  uint16   Capabilities[];
  string   CapabilityDescriptions[];
  string   Caption;
  string   CompressionMethod;
  uint32   ConfigManagerErrorCode;
  boolean  ConfigManagerUserConfig;
  string   CreationClassName;
  uint64   DefaultBlockSize;
  string   Description;
  string   DeviceID;
  boolean  ErrorCleared;
  string   ErrorDescription;
  string   ErrorMethodology;
  string   FirmwareRevision;
  uint32   Index;
  datetime InstallDate;
  string   InterfaceType;
  uint32   LastErrorCode;
  string   Manufacturer;
  uint64   MaxBlockSize;
  uint64   MaxMediaSize;
  boolean  MediaLoaded;
  string   MediaType;
  uint64   MinBlockSize;
  string   Model;
  string   Name;
  boolean  NeedsCleaning;
  uint32   NumberOfMediaSupported;
  uint32   Partitions;
  string   PNPDeviceID;
  uint16   PowerManagementCapabilities[];
  boolean  PowerManagementSupported;
  uint32   SCSIBus;
  uint16   SCSILogicalUnit;
  uint16   SCSIPort;
  uint16   SCSITargetId;
  uint32   SectorsPerTrack;
  string   SerialNumber;
  uint32   Signature;
  uint64   Size;
  string   Status;
  uint16   StatusInfo;
  string   SystemCreationClassName;
  string   SystemName;
  uint64   TotalCylinders;
  uint32   TotalHeads;
  uint64   TotalSectors;
  uint64   TotalTracks;
  uint32   TracksPerCylinder;
};
```

Top Portion oF Code Taken From:

http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial233_Getting-Disk-Drive-Information-using-WMI-and-Csharp.html

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to check when the device is connected the problem is much simpler. You need to check for the [`DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363205%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event. If you are creating a Windows Forms application this can be done by implementing [`IMessageFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter.aspx) interface and pass it to the [`AddMessageFiler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter.aspx) function in `Application`. If you are not using a Forms app you will need to derive a class from [`NativeWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.aspx) and override WndProc. Remeber to call [CreateHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.createhandle.aspx) so it will be added to the windows message queue.

Once you have the way to receive `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` you will need to parse it out. (the following was not written in a IDE so it has not been tested)

```
// Constants from from Dbt.h
const int WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x219;
const int DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = 0x8000; 
const uint DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE = 0x05;
const Guid GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE = new Guid("A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED");


bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
{
    if(m.Msg == case WM_DEVICECHANGE && m.WParam == DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL)
        var broadcast = (DEV_BROADCAST_HDR)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pnt, typeof(DEV_BROADCAST_HDR));
        if(broadcast.dbch_DeviceType == DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE)
        {
            var devInterface = (DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pnt, typeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE));
            if(devInterface.dbcc_classguid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE)
            {
                // devInterface.dbcc_name will contain the VID and PID for example:
                // \\?\USB#Vid_067b&Pid_2517#6&12115ad4&2&1#{GUID}
                DoSomthingSpecial(devInterface.dbcc_name);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct DEV_BROADCAST_HDR {
   public uint dbch_Size;
   public uint dbch_DeviceType;
   public uint dbch_Reserved;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE
{
        public int dbcc_size;
        public int dbcc_devicetype;
        public int dbcc_reserved;
        public Guid dbcc_classguid;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=255)]
        public string dbcc_name;
}
```

If you need to enumerate all devices already connected I would just recommend using the [WMI method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10058571/80274). If you want to see how to do it without WMI check out the code to [USBView](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/USBView-sample-application-e3241039) in the [Windows Driver Development Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11800), it may help you get you started.

Comment: This is much better solution for OP question because WMI is total overkill.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static bool GetDriveVidPid(string szDriveName, ref ushort wVID, ref ushort wPID)
{
   bool bResult = false;
   string szSerialNumberDevice = null;

   ManagementObject oLogicalDisk = new ManagementObject("Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID='" + szDriveName.TrimEnd('\\') + "'");
   foreach(ManagementObject oDiskPartition in oLogicalDisk.GetRelated("Win32_DiskPartition"))
   {
      foreach(ManagementObject oDiskDrive in oDiskPartition.GetRelated("Win32_DiskDrive"))
      {
         string szPNPDeviceID = oDiskDrive["PNPDeviceID"].ToString();
         if(!szPNPDeviceID.StartsWith("USBSTOR"))
            throw new Exception(szDriveName + " ist kein USB-Laufwerk.");

         string[] aszToken = szPNPDeviceID.Split(new char[] { '\\', '&' });
         szSerialNumberDevice = aszToken[aszToken.Length - 2];
      }
   }

   if(null != szSerialNumberDevice)
   {
      ManagementObjectSearcher oSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\CIMV2", "Select * from Win32_USBHub");
      foreach(ManagementObject oResult in oSearcher.Get())
      {
         object oValue = oResult["DeviceID"];
         if(oValue == null)
            continue;

         string szDeviceID = oValue.ToString();
         string[] aszToken = szDeviceID.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
         if(szSerialNumberDevice != aszToken[aszToken.Length - 1])
            continue;

         int nTemp = szDeviceID.IndexOf(@"VID_");
         if(0 > nTemp)
            continue;

         nTemp += 4;
         wVID = ushort.Parse(szDeviceID.Substring(nTemp, 4), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);

         nTemp += 4;
         nTemp = szDeviceID.IndexOf(@"PID_", nTemp);
         if(0 > nTemp)
            continue;

         nTemp += 4;
         wPID = ushort.Parse(szDeviceID.Substring(nTemp, 4), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);

         bResult = true;
         break;
      }
   }

   return bResult;
}
```